# Finding pattern in string PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a way to find a pattern in a PHP string. I am aware of `preg_match function` but that only returns a 1 or 0.

I have some deals like these

> '5% Off Baby Stationery'
>
> '$10 Off Orders Over $50'
>
> '$5 Off Orders Over $30'
>
> '$7.50 Off Orders Over $40'
>
> '5% Off Your Order'
>
> '11% Off Any Purchase'
>
> '$5 Off Orders Over $50'
>
> '10% Off All Orders'
>
> '$10 Off Orders Over $100'
>
> '$3 Shipping With Any Purchase'

What I am trying to do is get $x or $xx or $xxx or x% or xx% or xxx% from the deal texts.

I want to get the actual values rather than checking if the pattern exists.

For example, from

> '$10 Off Orders Over $100',

I want to get $10 and $100 and save them in a variable.

Comment: What have you tried? Your samples contain strings with two occurences of eg. $##, what should be matched then? first, last, all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `preg_match_all()` can be used to store the matches to another variable (third parameter of the function).

```
$str = '$10 Off Orders Over $100';
$matches = [];
$pattern = '/\$[0-9]*\.{0,1}[0-9]+/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);

echo $matches[0][0]; // $10
echo $matches[0][1]; // $100
```

Comment: Note that your pattern curerntly won't match `$5`, OPs examples don't contain decimal values, so you might not need to match them at all. Otherwise you can use `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?` for the numbers part.

Comment: Edited my answer. Just changed the first `+` to `*`. Some of OP's example does contain decimal values like the `$7.50`.

Comment: Also you must grab the percent values as well

Comment: @MateiMihai: How do I grab % values in the regex. If I have to get 10% off $100, how do I get those.